# How do I get a key from a OrderedDictionary in C# by index?

Tags: c#, ordereddictionary

How do I get the key and value of item from OrderedDictionary by index?

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not a direct built-in way to do this. This is because for an `OrderedDictionary` the index *is* the key; if you want the actual key then you need to track it yourself. Probably the most straightforward way is to copy the keys to an indexable collection:

```
// dict is OrderedDictionary
object[] keys = new object[dict.Keys.Count];
dict.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < dict.Keys.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Index = {0}, Key = {1}, Value = {2}",
        i,
        keys[i],
        dict[i]
    );
}
```

You could encapsulate this behavior into a new class that wraps access to the `OrderedDictionary`.

Comment: I did same but see once:

OrderedDictionary list = OrderItems;
        object strKey = list[e.OldIndex];
        DictionaryEntry dicEntry = new DictionaryEntry();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry DE in list)
        {
            if (DE.Value == strKey)
            {
                dicEntry.Key = DE.Key;
                dicEntry.Value = DE.Value;
            }
        }

Comment: @RedSwan: Where is the index?

Comment: The index is definitely *not* the key - those are necessarily distinct constructs in an ``OrderedDictionary``.

Comment: Downvoted because the index is not the key, as demonstrated in the answer by @martin-r-l

Answer (score 51):

```
orderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(index);
```

Comment: using `using System.Linq;`

Comment: With this code you get the element. But how do I get the key and the value as in the SO question?

Comment: `orderedDictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(index).Key.ToString();`

Comment: + 1 This should be the accepted answer actually. Verify here - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/ordereddictionary.cs,210

Answer (score 2):

I created some extension methods that get the key by index and the value by key using the code mentioned earlier.

```
public static T GetKey<T>(this OrderedDictionary dictionary, int index)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    try
    {
        return (T)dictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(index).Key;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public static U GetValue<T, U>(this OrderedDictionary dictionary, T key)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        return default(U);
    }

    try
    {
        return (U)dictionary.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().AsQueryable().Single(kvp => ((T)kvp.Key).Equals(key)).Value;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return default(U);
    }
}
```

Comment: If your intent is to return default values if the targeted index/key is not in the dictionary you have chosen an expensive way to do it.  Exceptions are very expensive relative to normal control-flow constructs like if/else.  It would be much better to check for out-of-bounds indices and non-existing keys yourself than to rely on an exception happening.