# How to get item name by position OrderDirectory

Tags: c#

```
public static OrderedDictionary Drinks = new OrderedDictionary();
Drinks["Water"] = 3;
Drinks["Coffee"] = 2
Drinks["Beer"] = 5;
```

How can I get Item name by position?
I want when i specify position 1 to get "Water".

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229951/how-to-get-key-from-ordereddictionary-in-c-sharp-by-index

Comment: Why use a dictionary if you want to access the data using a sequential index? In what circumstance could position `1` return `Water`?

Comment: I am unsure of what you are trying to accomplish... Why are you using an Ordered Dictionary and what do you want to do ? If we know more, we could help you better

Comment: What is the type of "Drinks" here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

For value:

```
 var result= (Drinks.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(2)).Value;
```

For Key

```
var result= (Drinks.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ElementAt(2)).Key;
```

Comment: Close. OP would like the `Key`, rather than the `Value`. Other than that, this works as requested - http://ideone.com/rmAU1h

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var result = Drinks.Keys.OfType<string>().ElementAt(0);
```

This will return first key of `OrderedDictionary`. Here you are sure that your key type is string. but if you are not sure data type of key then use `object`

like,

```
var result = Drinks.Keys.OfType<object>().ElementAt(0);
```