# OrderedDictionary key name at specified index

Tags: powershell, ordereddictionary, array-indexing

Given an ordered dictionary, I would like to get the key at index 0. I can of course do a loop, get the key of the first iteration and immediately break out of the loop. But I wonder if there is a way to do this directly?
My Google-Fu has not turned up anything, and some shots in the dark have failed too. I have tried things like

```
$hash[0].Name
```

and

```
$hash.GetEnumerator()[0].Name
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229951/how-do-i-get-a-key-from-a-ordereddictionary-in-c-sharp-by-index) discussion about doing it in C#, which lead to this

```
[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]$test.Item(0).Key
```

but that fails too. Is this just something that can't be done, or am I going down the wrong path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.Keys) collection:

```
$orderedHash = [ordered] @{ foo = 1; bar = 2 }

# Note the use of @(...)
@($orderedHash.Keys)[0] # -> 'foo'
```

Note:

- Use of `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), enumerates the `.Keys` collection and collects its elements in an `[object[]]` array, which enables access by positional indices.

  - The `.Keys` collection itself implements only the [`System.Collections.ICollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ICollection) interface, which supports enumeration, but not indexed access.
  - **`@(...)` to enable indexing will no longer be necessary in  PowerShell (Core) 7.3+** (.NET 7+), thanks to an improvement initiated by [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) via [GitHub issue #56835](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56835): The `.Keys` collection will then implement the [`System.Collections.IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList) interface, which *does* support positional indexing. Note that this **change will only apply to  *ordered* hashtables (`[ordered] @{ ... }`, [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary))**, not also to regular (unordered) [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) (`@{ ... }`) or other types implementing the [`System.Collections.IDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IDictionary) interface. However, iRon has created a ***follow-up proposal* to make the `.Keys` property indexable for *all (definition-)ordered and sorted dictionaries*** - see [GitHub issue #63537](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63537).
- `.Name` is an alias property provided by PowerShell; the type-native property containing each [`System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry)'s key is `.Key`

Comment: Thanks, @iRon. I've added a link to the new issue to the answer. Arguably, for consistency even _unordered_ dictionaries should have indexable `.Keys` properties (don't know if there'd be concerns about unnecessary overhead).

Comment: Notably, `$orderedHash[0].keys` doesn't work and some mishmash of `$orderedHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{...}` is subpar to this method. I can't believe how long it took me to find this! The best I found before stumbling upon your answer is: `$i=0; $orderedHash.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object{ if ($i -ne $index){++$i} $myKey =  $_.key}`